# SQL Server - Using AVG on a VARCHAR column with Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to use `AVG` on a `VARCHAR` column , but I am keep getting error from SQL server:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    PivotData
PIVOT 
    (AVG(CAST(ClinRefResultValue AS decimal))
     FOR ClinicalRefSensorName IN ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E])
    ) AS PVTTable
```

The error I am getting is :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 95
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

I can not figure what I am doing wrong !

Source data :

```
With PivotData AS
(
    select 
        [dbo].[ClinRefFile].[DonorID], 
        [dbo].[ClinRefFile].[Sample], 
        [dbo].[ClinRefSensorMaster].[ClinicalRefSensorName],
        [dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail].ClinRefTime,
        [dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail].ClinRefResultValue
    from 
        [dbo].[ClinRefFile],
        [dbo].[ClinRefFileTypeMaster],
        [dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail],
        [dbo].[ClinRefSensorMaster]
    where 
        [dbo].[ClinRefFile].[ClinRefFileID] = [dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail].[ClinRefFileID] 
        and [dbo].[ClinRefFile].[ClinRefTypeID] = [dbo].[ClinRefFileTypeMaster].[ClinRefTypeID] 
        and [dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail].[ClinRefSensorID] = [dbo].[ClinRefSensorMaster].[ClinicalRefSensorID] 
        and [dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail].ClinRefTime = 'Average'
)
```

Comment: Can you include your source table and expected results?

Comment: Apply the `cast` inside the CTE.

Comment: @NWest  Just updated the question ! I just want get the Average of the results for each sensor.

Comment: @bluefeet can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: @user3033921 Don't cast it inside of that `avg()` - cast it in your subquery - `cast([dbo].[ClinRefResultDetail].ClinRefResultValue  AS decimal)`

Comment: @bluefeet thanks that worked, still not sure what was wrong with using it with Pivot !

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s  That's equivalent to Inner Joint and there is absolutely nothing wrong in using it.